# How do i save code changes to an Excel VBA add-in?

Tags: excel, vba, save, excel-2007, add-in

I've made an add-in for Excel in VBA and now I need to make changes to the code, but the file won't save.  I open the .xlam file, I make the changes, ctrl-S to save with no errors popping up, close down.  But when I reopen, none of the change I made are there.  What gives? is there some special way I have to save an add-in to make changes stick?

Comment: Are you pressing save in the Excel file or in the VBA application?

Answer (score 8):

In the VB editor, select the project in the Project Explorer pane, then in the Immediate Window (Ctrl + G) enter this line and press Enter:

ThisWorkbook.Save

Answer (score 2):

I have had occurrences where it did not look like the Add-In was saved.  I had to unload the Add-In, restart Excel, and then reload the Add-In.  The saved changes were there, just not shown until the Add-In was reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues with add-ins not saving when the default Excel save is made; instead, you should make sure that you always save from inside the VBA editor.  Beyond that, make sure you haven't checked the "Lock project for viewing" checkbox or added a password -- these can both be found on the "Protection" tab of the "Project Properties" dialog, the 5th item in the "tools" menu.

Answer (score 1):

I 've have a button on Sheet1 of the .xlam file with the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = True
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

When I want to save the .xlam file, I select ThisWorksheet in the Project Explorer window, and then change the value of the IsAddin property to false, which displays sheet1 of the .xlam file.  I click the button, which changes it back to an Addin file and saves the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have also had the issue that the VBE does not save code changes in a .xlam add-in I created. By chance I discovered that if there are any workbooks open (other than the hidden .xlam), the VBE save does not happen, but if all other workbooks are closed, then the VBE does save changes in the add-in.  It's an awkward workaround to save and close all workbooks in order to save the code changes, then reopen them, but it is faster than always exporting the changed modules, closing Excel, reopening it and the VBE, and importing the saved .bas files.  Maybe that gives someone (at Microsoft?) a hint of why the VBE isn't saving as it should.